# Just introducing myself to TMPing, and came across a quirk

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c1001

I was just trying to learn the syntax of the beginner things, and how it worked when I was making this short bit of code in VS2008. The code below works in adding numbers 1 to 499, but if I add 1 to 500, the compiler bugs out giving me:

`fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

And I was just wondering why that is. Is there some limit to how much code the compiler can generate or something and it just happened to be a nice round number of 500 for me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < int b >
struct loop {
    enum { sum = loop< b - 1 >::sum + b };
};

template <>
struct loop< 0 > {
    enum { sum = 0 };
};

int main() {
    cout << "Adding the numbers from 1 to 499 = " << loop< 499 >::sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Judging by the error code, it's VC++. Maybe it just can't handle all that recursion. Use GCC instead.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume with gcc (and by extension g++) the default maximum template recursion depth is `500` as at least on my machine I managed to reproduce your problems with a (slightly better) warning message. Compiling `loop<500>::sum` worked fine but trying to compile `loop<501>::sum` failed.

If you are using gcc (or g++) the solution is to compile it with `-ftemplate-depth-##` (Where ## is the maximum allowed depth).

So for example to compile `main.cpp` with a maximum template recursion depth of 2000

```
g++ -ftemplate-depth-2000 main.cpp
```

Or convert the code to this:

```
template < int b >
struct loop {
    enum { sum = (b*(b+1))/2 };
};
```

(But I will admit the above code doesn't help you learn about template metaprogramming)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that formula. Thanks though for the info.

Answer (score 5):

VC9 (VS2008) crashes with numbers > 499. The code itself is valid and compilers are even permitted to stop compilation after a certain amount of recursive instantiations, giving a diagnostic. However, an *Internal Compiler Error* (colloquially also called *ICE*) certainly isn't a nice diagnostic.

An ICE is always an error of the compiler. It might be caused by an error in the code, too, but if that's the case, then the compiler failed to show a proper diagnostic for that error. If the error is reproducible, you should submit a bug report to the compiler vendor, so they can fix their error.

When reporting such an error (here or elsewhere) you should never fail to provide the exact compiler version you used.

Comment: @Bill: Damn, it seems I read too quickly. Sorry for that and thanks for pointing this out. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the Output window:

> c:\projects\cpptemp3\cpptemp3.cpp(9):
>   fatal error C1001: An internal error
>   has occurred in the compiler.
>       (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1411)
>       **To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program
>   near the locations listed above.**

Comment: I wasn't looking for a way to circumvent the issue since this isn't really a program. I was try to understand why the issue was happening at 500 recursive iterations but not 400.

Comment: @Justen: You've reverse-engineered the template evaluational stack depth inside the compiler.  500, nice round number.  Although I would have picked 512.